# Alerting Linux' Real-Time FIFO Scheduler

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, scheduling

I'm trying to change the implementation of Real-Time Scheduler in 3.13.3. As far as i know, in Real-Time FIFO Scheduling the Kernel simply keeps a queue of processes with the same priority and allocates the CPU to the process at the end of queue (head), and adds process to the tail... I want to add an extra field to the PCB structure (task_struct), so that the Kernel sorts the queue based on this new field. Say we define this new field as `int extra_priority`, i want the kernel to give the precedence to processes with higher `extra_priority` whenever choosing the next process from queue to execute...
I'm wondering, where does this whole "popping the process from queue" and "pushing the new process to the tail of queue" take place? So i could call my "sort by extra_priority" whenever the queue changes, in order to keep the queue sorted all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't modified process scheduling of real time processes. Based on the following passage from the book *Understanding the Linux Kernel*, you may be able to achieve that by modifying `scheduler_tick()` function to alter the order of the real time FIFO processes.

> **Updating the time slice of a real-time process**
>
> If the current process is a FIFO real-time process, scheduler_tick()
>   has nothing to do. In this case, in fact, current cannot be preempted
>   by lower or equal priority processes, thus it does not make sense to
>   keep its time slice counter up-to-date. If current is a Round Robin
>   real-time process, scheduler_tick() decreases its time slice counter
>   and checks whether the quantum is exhausted:
>
> ```
> if (current->policy == SCHED_RR && !--current->time_slice) {
> current->time_slice = task_timeslice(current);
> current->first_time_slice = 0;
> set_tsk_need_resched(current);
> list_del(&current->run_list);
> list_add_tail(&current->run_list,
> this_rq()->active->queue+current->prio);
> }
> ```